# Why can't I call a function from within a ui-grid cell-template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I have a cellTemplate that's supposed to make a row editable when clicked. Works so far. However when this is done, also a function should be called, which just isn't happening:

colDef:

```
cellEditableCondition: ($scope) => $scope.row.editable
```

what I tried in cellTemplate:

```
ng-click="row.editable = true;" //works
ng-click="row.editable = true; console.log('WTF?')" //works, no log
ng-click="console.log('WTF?'); row.editable = true;" //works, no log
ng-click="console.log('WTF?')" //no log either
```

When you click the button, the cells become editable, just as intended. But nothing's printed to the console . And I can't seem to figure out why.
Is there something I'm missing? How do I call a function from within a cellTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console` belongs to the javascript `window` object. It is not inside angular's scope. If you want to use it in an angular template, in your controller add this:

```
$scope.console = window.console;
```

Comment: I was aware of this and usually set `$rootScope.console = console;` in app.run(). However I now learned that ui-grid uses isolated scopes that do not inherit. Thanks for leading me on the right track!

Comment: Sorry, the Return key sending the comment right away will drive me nuts some day. I edited my last comment. Thanks again, Tarun!